# jQuery not running on mobile browers

Tags: jquery, html, ios, iphone, css

So I'm working on the mobile menu for a website and it seemed like everything was running smoothly until I started testing it on a few devices. Resized window on a desktop was perfectly fine but mobiles are doing some strange things.

Take a look at the jsFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/s9Hpa/2/

It should give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.
If you look at that link on a desktop the menu button will toggle the navigation div no problem but I have found that when viewing it with an iPhone 4 on IOS6, the menu button only changes to its hover state and doesn't execute the jQuery. This is the same thing I'm finding with the website I'm working on.

The html follows this structure:

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li id="home" class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            ...
            <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="menu"></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

On the desktop site #menu is set to `display:none;` and under 480px it is set to `display:block;` and `#navigation` is set to `display: none;` Nothing particularly fancy is happening besides restyling for a mobile screen.

As you can see I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 from Google.

Then I'm trying to use jQuery to set a click event on #menu which will toggle `#navigation`. This is what my current code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    };
    $('#menu').click(function () {
        $('#navigation').slideFadeToggle();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if(window.innerWidth > 500) 
            {
                 $("#navigation").removeAttr("style");
            }
   });
});
```

I feel like I'm obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It doesn't seem to be the fault of `slideFadeToggle`, I have tried without it with no change. I have tried a bunch of different versions of jQuery, no change there either. I have made sure JavaScript is allowed on the phone.

The actual website can be found here: http://www.bridgeport.net.au/new/index.html

You can see there is some animation with the header and captions and the image will cycle through a few. I'm finding that IOS devices (I haven't been able to test on Android so far) aren't running any of these animations either.

Everything works perfectly fine on a desktop when you resize the window but something isn't working right on a phone. Even the caption fonts on the home page are different on a phone and they are google web fonts using @import in the css like so:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200|Josefin+Slab:400italic);
```

I was thinking it was a problem with the hosting server until I made the jsFiddle page and found the same problems. Now I'm stumped.

Edit: I just tested it on an iPhone 5 with IOS7 and found it is doing the same thing.

Edit 2: I realised that the jQuery I was using wasn't taking into account touch events so I changed to click function to:

```
$('#menu').on('touchstart click', function(){
    $('#navigation').slideFadeToggle();
});
```

And added in cursor: pointer; to #menu as per some suggestions I found around stack overflow.

Still no change as far as I can tell. New fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Amp3rsand/s9Hpa/14/

Answer (score 1):

instead of this.animate do $(this).animate and see if this works. i don't have iphone but i tested it in android default browser and chrome (for android), it works.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the help. I just tested it and found it isn't working on my iphone safari or chrome still. Was it working on the android browser before the change?